# Правильно ли реализован шаблон?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода, шаблоны-с++

Работает как очистка памяти и все остальные шаблоны, без указания размера и типа, но правильно ли реализованы сами шаблоны?

```
namespace msafe
{
    // используется исключительно для освобождения COM объектов
    template <class T>
    void srel(T& t)
    {
        if (t)
        {
            t->Release();
            t = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // используется для удаления объектов классов, созданных пользователем/разработчиком
    template <class T>
    void sdel(T& t)
    {
        if (t)
        {
            delete t;
            t = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // используется для упрощения очистки памяти под структуры
    template <typename T>
    void* setz(T& t)
    {
        return memset(&t, 0, sizeof(T));
    }

    // используется для удаления массивов из памяти
    template <class T>
    void sdel_arr(T& t)
    {
        if (t)
        {
            delete[] t;
            t = nullptr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: интересно, что это за тип T, чтобы с ним можно было так работать?

Comment: Посмотрите std::is_same<>, здесь уместно будет.

Comment: @Abyx добавлено описание для каждого из шаблонов

Comment: Лучше бы сделать это классом, и инкапсулировать этот `t` внутри. Тогда ничего не потеряется и не забудется :)

Answer (score 1):

Местами надо добавить *.

Например,

```
template <class T>
void srel(T*& t)
{
    if (t)
    {
        t->Release();
        t = nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в током случае будет передаваться указатель на указатель или же указатель?

Comment: Передастся указатель. То есть, если вы подставили в srel MyClass*, то компилятор при дедукции аргумента шаблона сообразит, что под T понимается MyClass. Именно MyClass, а не MyClass*.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, Ваш код чреват ошибками выполнения. Условие в `if`, соответствие форм `new` и `delete`, гарантии наличия ф-ии члена `Release()`. Что, если, к примеру, пользователь вызовет функцию `sdel()` для С-массива или вообще для неуказательного типа? Будет явно неприятно.

Лучше объявляйте деструктор и в нем пишите, что Вы хотите дополнительно сделать при удалении. А если хотите работать с указателями, то используйте прокси-классы, например, `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr` и т.п. Они позволяют при создании объекта указать пользовательский удалитель, например, некую функцию или лямбду. Правда, этого нельзя сделать, если Вы будете использовать `make`-функции. Также интеллектуальные указатели не работают с типами массива, поскольку у них используется инструкция `delete` без `[]`. Но и это не проблема - STL изобилует контейнерами на любой вкус.

Comment: `srel` вызывается исключительно для COM объектов.

Answer (score 0):

При выводе параметра шаблона игнорируется его константность и ссылочность, но при этом не игнорируется указатель

```
int x;
const int& crx = x;
int* px = &x;

template<class T>
void f(T t) { /* ... */ }

f(x); // T = int, в функцию передается копия x по значению
f(crx); // T = int, модификаторы const и & игнорируются
f(px); // T = int*, указатель не игнорируется
```

чтобы аргументу функции указать const и & для типа, необходимо прописать их явно

```
template<class T>
void f(const T& t) { /* ... */ }

f(x); // T = const int&, в функцию передается копия x по значению
f(crx); // T = int, модификаторы const и & на этапе вывода типа для T игнорируются, но добавляются для типа аргумента, т. к. они указаны
```

можно так же передавать и указатель (лучше так и делать, это показывает явное намерение, что шаблонная функция ожидает в качестве параметра указатель)

```
template<class T>
void f(T* t) { /* ... */ }

f(x); // ошибка при компиляции, функция принимает только указатели
f(px); // T = int*
f(&px); // T = int**
```

со всем этим хочу так же выделить один момент на счет отбрасывания const

```
template<class T>
void f(T t) { /* ... */ }

const int* const cpcx = *x; // константный указатель на константный int
f(x); // T = const int*, отбросился const, который отвечает за константность указателя, но остался тот, который отвечает за константность того, что лежит по этому указателю
```

Comment: @Birdy для проверки можно использовать, например, макрос `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, определенный в gcc, пример - https://ideone.com/pMarFD